# Vue model that doesn't exist on creation

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is my code:

```
      <lm-contact-type-select
          v-model="value.dimensions[0]"
      />
```

and the problem is that sometimes value doesn't have dimensions, which cause an error. What can I do to prevent it?

Comment: I'd say just use a "nullish coalescing operator" which comes in handy sometimes. `value.dimensions[0] ?? DEFAULT_VALUE`. Unless you're looking to remove the input, then use a `v-if` to check only if dimensions exists, example: `v-if="value.dimensions != undefined"`

Comment: Create first, nullish can be handy, but may be also misleading because value not storing anywhere

Answer (score 0):

You have to check before render this component. So,

```html
<div v-if="value.dimensions.length">
    <lm-contact-type-select
        v-model="value.dimensions[0]"
    />
</div>
```